# javafx: How can I make a label automatically updates its text color depending on a String Property?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically my Item class has two `StringProperty` s, namely `amount` and `upOrDown`. Their values will automatically update overtime.

All I have done so far is to bind `label1`'s `textProperty` to the first `StringProperty`, `amount`.

```
fxLabel1.textProperty().bind(item.amountProperty());
```

**Question 1:**

What I also want to do is to bind the color of this label's text to the second String Property `upOrDown`, i.e. the text color is gold when `upOrDown` is `UP` and purple when `upOrDown` is `DOWN`. How can I achieve this?

**Question 2:**

Second, I want to display an image in a separate label (not sure if label is the best option here) depending on the string value of `upOrDown`. Similar to the exercise, I want to display `image1` in the label when `upOrDown` is `UP` and `image2` when `upOrDown` is `DOWN`. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use binding for this :

```
label.textFillProperty().bind(
             Bindings.when(upOrDown.isEqualTo("UP"))
                                        .then(Color.GOLD).otherwise(Color.PURPLE));
```

Similarly, for your question 2 you can use Bindings for loading image into an ImageView.

Comment: how would you handle the case where there are three cases, i.e. up , down , no change ?

Comment: How would you implement something similar using a `if..else..` ?

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)